# Universal iOS App : UIWebView in detailViewController does not display content for iPad part

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiwebview

I am working on a **Universal iOS Application on Xcode 4**. It's my first time trying to create an iPhone/iPad app. I am using the **Master-Detail Application Template**.
This app is roughly a RSS Feed Reader.
I have followed this tutorial to get the big idea: http://cocoadevblog.com/iphone-tutorial-creating-a-rss-feed-reader

I succeed to make the iPhone part working but i have a problem with the UIWebView in the iPad part.

Here is the code which may not be correct.

From MasterViewController ... :

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
    if (!self.detailViewController) {
        NSDictionary *theItem = [items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];  
        DetailViewController *nextController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];
        [nextController setDetailItem:theItem];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:nextController animated:YES];
    }

}
else {
    if (!self.detailViewController){
        NSDictionary *theItem = [items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];  
        DetailViewController *nextController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController_iPad" bundle:nil];
        [nextController setDetailItem:theItem];
        self.detailViewController = nextController;
    }
    else {
        [self.detailViewController setDetailItem:[self.items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    }
}
```

}

... to DetailViewController, here is the implementation of setDetailItem: and configureView :

```
- (void)setDetailItem:(id)newDetailItem
{
    if (_detailItem != newDetailItem) {
        _detailItem = newDetailItem;       
        // Update the view.
        [self configureView];
    }
    if (self.masterPopoverController != nil) {
        [self.masterPopoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
    }        
}

- (void)configureView
{
    // Update the user interface for the detail item.
    if (_detailItem) {
        NSLog(@"webpage creation");
        NSString *html = [_detailItem objectForKey:@"title"];

        [...html stuff added to html string...]

        webView = nil;
        webView.delegate=self;
        //[self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]]];
        [self.webView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];

        NSLog(@"webView loaded");
    }
}
```

I got a blank screen on the detailView pane when i select a row on the MasterView (MasterView/detailView -> in the universal app case, the iPad app is a splitview style App).

I linked the webView in InterfaceBuilder (for both iPhone/iPad .xib files), i received every NSLog, but i cannot make the UIWebViewDelegate answer me even if i implemented it. Of course, the comment with loading the Google Home page doesnt work either.

**UPDATE 25/10/11:**

I created an new Universal App, a simple one, where i added a UIWebView and i try to load Google webPage.
I can load the page from the viewDidLoad/viewDidAppear (detailViewController) but not from configureView (detailViewController) which is called when i select a row (fire the setDetailItem in detailViewController).
It is like i cannot modify it after loading the panel. There is something I dont get.
(The code I use to launch a webpage is the same code line than the comment above in configureView)

**UPDATE 26/10/11**

The webView has no value (null) in configureView (when i try to display it for a selected row). I tried this, which is not working but I (obviously/at least) get a value for webView in that case :

```
- (void)configureView{
if (_detailItem) {

    UIWebView *tempWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] init];
    self.webView = tempWebView;

    NSLog(@"webpage creation");
    NSString *html = [_detailItem objectForKey:@"title"];

    [...html stuff added to html string...]

    //[self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]]];
    [self.webView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];


    self.webView.delegate=self;//better to add "self" to get it working
    NSLog(@"webView loaded");
    NSLog(@"%@",self.webView); //i got this : <UIWebView: 0x6a5a550; frame = (0 0; 0 0); layer = <CALayer: 0x6a59750>>
}}
```

By writting "self.webView.delegate=self;" i got the delegate answering me. However this one produce two answers (??) like if there were two webView running ?:

> 2011-10-26 10:49:57.089 APPName[18334:f803] didStart Loading web Page
>
> 2011-10-26 10:49:59.416 APPName[18334:f803] didStart Loading web
>   Page
>
> 2011-10-26 10:49:59.523 APPName[18334:f803] finished loading web
>   page
>
> 2011-10-26 10:49:59.806 APPName[18334:f803] finished loading
>   web page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got it working.

However, the only solution i've found is to create another project with STORYBOARD and not xib files, which was I guess the problem.

So i dont really have the answer for my problem, but i guess it is for sure a problem of link in the xib files. But i didnt find it.

With Storyboard, I worked out the iPad version easily, but not the iPhone version... until I found the good tutorial : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NHIOx_1mz-Q

So for the Storyboard, i deleted the tableview section (inserted by default) and put this code :

MasterViewController

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
    NSLog(@"SELECT ROW IPHONE");
    if (!self.detailViewController){
        NSDictionary *theItem = [items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];  
        DetailViewController *nextController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Detail"];
        [nextController setDetailItem:theItem];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:nextController animated:YES];
   }

}
else {
    NSLog(@"SELECT ROW IPAD");
    self.detailViewController.detailItem = [self.items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
```

}

DetailViewController

```
- (void)configureView{
// Update the user interface for the detail item.
if (self.detailItem) {
    self.detailDescriptionLabel.text = [self.detailItem description];
    self.webView.delegate=self;
    NSString *html = @"";
    [...html stuff...]
    [self.webView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
}
```

}

I dont mention it, but i also created and linked webview of course.

If someone find the answer for the xib version of a simple project with TableView linked to a detailView for iPad (on Universal iOS project), i would like to ear it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will fix your problem completely, but at least this line is suspicious:

```
    webView = nil;
```

It looks to me like you are setting the webView to nil just before you set the delegate? If it is nil at that point, there is no way that the delegate is going to be set.  In fact, when you try to send it any messages, it will just ignore them.

(Also that may be leaking memory.)

Comment: true, this was stupid from me.
however, it doesnt get me anything more (neither the webview working nor the UIWebViewDelegate errors/output).

Comment: Ok, so I guess the next question is: where is the webView allocated?  Is it initialized in code or do you use a .xib file, and, if it is in a .xib file, are you sure it is connected?  If you put NSLog(@"%@", webView); after, say, NSLog(@"webView loaded"); does the webView itself have a value?

Comment: atch...
The webView has no value (null).

Comment: There is something that is weird for me when i compare this universal application to my iPad app i did last week. It is that in IB for the iPad app (splitViewbased) there is an outlet from RootViewController linked to my detailView. 

But here, even if it is splitView, there is not. Actually, that is why i create a new detailViewController foreach row. And whith the configuration of the universal i dont know how i would be able to connect through IB (no mainWindow.xib).

Comment: i created a temporary webview and set webview to this temporary webview i alloc and init, but if i get a value for my webView, i dont get it displayed

Answer (score 0):

- A split view controller must always be the root of any interface you create.
- The panes of your split-view interface may then contain navigation controllers, 
  tab bar controllers,…
- the split view controller automatically handles most of the rotation behaviors

And we can’t use UISplitViewController inside TabBars !!